# Is it safe to have 2nd SSD with dangerous software? (disk encryption of the first drive turned on)

Tags: malware, virus, disk-encryption

Currently, I'm using 1 SSD and I think it's safe. I'm thinking about using 2nd SSD for unsafe software (pirated software). Is it possible that the virus on the 2nd drive can reach the 1st drive, somehow damage the PC, or bring other unwanted effects?
There is a BitLocker disk encryption turned on on the 1st drive. I'm not going to provide the key to unlock it to the 2nd system, also I'm not going to open or execute the files of the 2nd drive by the 1st drive system.

Both systems are Windows 10.
Also, I thought about using a virtual machine for this purpose but found the information here that it's not 100% safe since the virtual machine can execute programs on the same CPU, which is unsafe, and there are some other vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand you correctly reading between your lines, you are talking about a dual boot system with two drives and the one with your sensitive system being encrypted. And to execute suspicious programs you boot the second system and do not provide the decryption key to that system.

In this case it is possible that the data on your encrypted disk could be corrupted by malware. Leading to data loss. Therefore make a backup or detach the drive with the sensitive system before.

And speaking of the possibility for malware to break out off a virtual machine, it is unlikely but possible a malware is programmed to survive rebooting to your sensitive system e.g. by altering firmware of your computer hardware or writing to the possibly unencrypted master boot record of your sensitive drive.

Comment: For a bit more detail, the 2nd drive can't really read data from the 1st drive. It can, however, just write garbage to the 1st drive. It's like you don't need to understand what a book is saying to start erasing stuff from said book with bleach & fire.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm using 1 SSD and I think it's safe.

You are "safe" in this sense when you have a full backup of your ssd which is not physically connected to any running computer.

> Is it possible that the virus on the 2nd drive can reach the 1st drive, somehow damage the PC, or bring other unwanted effects?

Absolutely yes. If malware runs on your computer, it is trivial for the malware to destroy all of your data, no matter on which disk the data is stored in.

You should never run malware directly on your system. Either you use a dedicated computer for that or (more practically) you use a virtual machine like virtual-box or vmware with a clean OS (without any private data) to execute malware.

> I thought about using a virtual machine for this purpose but found the information here that it's not 100% safe since the virtual machine can execute programs on the same CPU

This can be the only problem using a virtual machine. It is rare that attacks like this will work (depends on the malware you are using). But using a virtual machine is **much** more safe than using no virtual machine.

Comment: So if I have a full backup of the first drive, is it safe to use the second drive?